# H2O .savemodel on network path not working

Tags: r, file, h2o

We have h2o cluster on linux machine (ran through command line), and we are connecting it from our local machine (Windows) which is on the same network.
When we try to call saveModel we are getting errors.

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://10.0.0.4:54321/99/Models.bin/)

//Code to load model from local machine,IDE- Rstudio

```
ModelName <- "GLM_model_R_1522217891094_1279"
modelpath <-file.path("file://dsvm-dev/Models",ModelName)
Model.h2o <- h2o.loadModel(modelpath)
```

//to save model

```
h2o.saveModel(object = best_model,path = "file://dsvm-dev/Models2/",force = TRUE)
```

Please suggest any alternate ways to save model to local machine(Windows) instead of on server. Also while saving it on server it saves to library folder, because we do not have access to machine.

Comment: Try to add a reproducible example so other members can help you better.

Comment: Code is same only thing is we are connecting to h2o cluster which is on linux machine. But while calling saveModel on it, it is not able find the network path. it is searching for authority component.

Comment: it would be easier to help you, with a reproducible example, you will get for sure more answers. This is a good practice... In general, I ensure the path is in a Canonical form and the folder exists, for example before `saveModel` I do: `modelpath <- normalizePath(modelpath)` and `dir.create(modelpath, showWarnings = FALSE)`. Try this and see if there is no an issue in the way the path is represented. I posed a question related, (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833097/how-to-specify-the-file-name-when-saving-the-model-using-h2o-package-from-r)) that may help you.

Comment: Path is in UNC format, I have shared folder from windows VM, and it is Azure active directory authenticated, so it was giving authority required exception.sometimes precondition failed.

Comment: Solution- https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5648, Mount the windows drive or add the users to one group and access model using winscp from linux machine. Mount option is worked well for our team.