# Possible to set file name for h2o.save_model() (rather then simply use the model_id value)?

Tags: h2o

Trying to save an h2o model with some specific name that differs from the model's `model_id` field, but trying something like...

```py
h2o.save_model(model=model,
               path='/some/path/then/filename',
               force=False)
```

just creates a dir/file structure like

```sh
some
   |__path
         |__then
              |__filename
                        |__<model_id>
```

as opposed to

```sh
some
   |__path
         |__then
              |__filename
```

Is this possible to do from the `save_model` method?

I can't / hesitate to simply change the `model_id` before calling the save method because the model names have timestamps appended to them to avoid name collisions with other models that may be on the h2o cluster (am trying to remove these timestamps when saving on disk and simplifying the name on the cluster before saving creates a time where naming collision can occur if other processes are also attempting to save such a model (of, say, a different timestamp)).

Any way to get this behavior or other common alternatives / workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible, however I created a feature request [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6622).  There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833097/how-to-specify-the-file-name-when-saving-the-model-using-h2o-package-from-r) which shows a solution for R (could be adapted to Python).  The work-around is just to rename the file manually using a few lines of R/Python code.